# In videos and images, strange color streaks on one monitor in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, calibration

I just did a clean install of Windows 10 (May 2020 Update).

Now, on one monitor only (I have a two-monitor setup), I see strange color streaks in some videos and images (Netflix, PHPStorm load screen, and others).

I see the issues on a BenQ BL3201PT.

For example, this:

[image: color streak example]

Interesting, if I turn on **Color filters** in Windows 10 and set to **Grayscale**, the entire display is grayscale except for these areas of color distortion:

[image]

What I did so far

- Reset all the settings on the monitor (in the monitor's menu).
- Calibrated the display using the built-in Windows tool.
- Updated to the latest graphics driver (using NVidia GTX 1070).
- Unplugged the display and plugged it back in.

Also, I noticed that [opening Flux](https://justgetflux.com/) makes the problem worse.

Since I was using Windows 10 on this exact same machine prior to the clean install without this issue, I'm confident it's software-related, but I don't know where to go to debug further.

I don't know what to call this problem, so even a hint of the correct search term would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I realized that with the screenshots I posted, you can't see the rings.

In any case, I found the source of the problem: **When you unplug the monitor cable to test, you have to unplug both ends, not just one.** D'oh!